# google caja not building

Tags: html-sanitizing, google-caja

Where can I download the file html-css-sanitizer-minified.js? I'd rather download the file than build caja myself. Reason: I tried building caja and got the errors below. Any Clues?

```
Version.set:
     [exec] Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "tools\svnve
rsion-nocolon": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified


Version.update:

build.info:

HtmlParser:
    [javac] Compiling 55 source files to c:\google-caja\third_party\java\htmlpar
ser\lib
    [javac] error: error reading c:\google-caja\third_party\java\jetty\lib\jetty
-util.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading c:\google-caja\third_party\java\jetty\lib\jetty
.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Caja doesn't build on Windows.  You can get the latest version of the sanitizer here:
http://www.gstatic.com/caja/5030/html-sanitizer-minified.js